# HTML CSS Button Positioning

Tags: html, css, button, position, pressed

I have 4 buttons in a header div. I have placed them all using margins top and left in css so they are all next to each other in one line. Nothing fancy.

Now I'm trying to do an action when the button is pressed the button text moves down a little bit.

I'm using this code in CSS :

```
    #btnhome:active{
    line-height : 25px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="header">           
        <button id="btnhome">Home</button>          
        <button id="btnabout">About</button>
        <button id="btncontact">Contact</button>
        <button id="btnsup">Help Us</button>           
        </div>
```

Button CSS example :

```
#btnhome {  
    margin-left: 121px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 84px;
    height: 45px;   
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: white;   
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

Also those buttons work on a header background, I'm sure it has something to do with these settings :

```
#header {
    background-image: url(images/navbar588.png);
    height: 48px;
    width: 588px;
    margin: 2em auto;   
    }
```

It works well but the only problem is that the all other buttons also move their text down? Why Is that? Aren't I clearly clarifying that I want to use #btnhome only? All the buttons have completely different ID's. All buttons have the same CSS settings except the margins. What do I need to edit?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you show the html for the other buttons. I would agree that your CSS does look like it should only apply to an item with an ID of btnhome

Comment: I think it might be because you're setting line-height, and thus the whole DOM gets pushed down. but we would need to see the HTML to be sure. personally, I'd just use `margin-top: 25px`

Comment: Lack of code is the path to the Dark side. Lack of code leads to anger... Anger leads to hate... Hate leads to suffering...

Comment: @SimonMartin I'm sorry guys, I have updated with more extra juicy code for you!

Comment: It's not that the text is being moved down, but the entire button. It just seems that way because of the transparent background and no border.

Comment: @sooper But isn't the "line height" used only for the text within the button?

Comment: I mean the buttons that are alongside the one you're pressing, they're being moved down as if `margin-top: 1px;` was being applied. This doesn't help, just an observation, sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as I expected, yeah, it's because the whole DOM element is being pushed down. You have multiple options. You can put the buttons in separate divs, and `float` them so that they don't affect each other. the simpler solution is to just set the `:active` button to `position:relative;` and use `top` instead of margin or line-height. example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5CZRP/

Answer (score 1):

try changing that line-height change to a margin-top or padding-top change instead

```
#btnhome:active{
margin-top : 25px;
}
```

Edit:
You could also try adding a span inside the button

```
<div id="header">           
    <button id="btnhome"><span>Home</span></button>          
    <button id="btnabout">About</button>
    <button id="btncontact">Contact</button>
    <button id="btnsup">Help Us</button>           
</div>
```

Then style that

```
#btnhome span:active { padding-top:25px;}
```

Comment: I have tried that, also check the updated question, It has one more valuable clue!

Comment: I have tried with span and your code but nothing happened. Then I tried with line height and your span way :

 and still all the texts from buttons moved.

'#btnhome span:active { line-height:25px;}'

Answer (score 0):

Use margins instead of line-height and then apply float to the buttons. By default they are displaying as `inline-block`, so when one is pushed down the hole line is pushed down with him. Float fixes this:

```
#header button {
    float:left;
}
```

Here's a working [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pc6K/).

Comment: Yeah I did, same thing happens..That's why I tried alternatively with lineheight in the first place...

Answer (score -1):

```
[type=submit]{
    margin-left: 121px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    width: 84px;
    height: 40px;   
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
}
```